# Using sizeof on Flexible member array's first element before memory allocation is Undefined Behaviour?

Tags: c, structure, sizeof, c99, flexible-array-member

If we have structure with flexible member array like :-

```
struct test{
    int n;
    int b[];
};
```

Then even before malloc is done, If we try to print like :-

```
struct test t;
printf("%lu",sizeof(t.b[0]);
```

Does this fall under Undefined behaviour?

C99 says this about flexible member arrays :-

> "If this array would have no elements, it behaves as if
> it had one element but the behaviour is undefined if any attempt is made to access that
> element or to generate a pointer one past it."

So accessing `b[0]` is undefined behaviour but will it apply to sizeof operator too given it is compile-time operator and `t.b[0]` is never accessed here at runtime?

When I tried this in gcc compiler, I have output as 4 bytes but if it falls under undefined behaviour, then we cannot take this output for granted until and unless gcc has given some extension which I am not sure in this case.

Comment: note: use `%zu` to print the result of `sizeof` operator, it has type `size_t`

Comment: No, that's perfectly fine. The same is true for the common malloc pattern `int *a = malloc(5 * sizeof *a);`. `sizeof` only evalutes the type, not the value.

Answer (score 5):

Since the argument to `sizeof` is not evaluated (unless, VLA), you're safe here.

In your case, `t.b[0]` is a complete type, `int` - to be specific. hence this is well defined. Matter of fact, you can also use `sizeof(t.b[100])`, since it's not evaluated, the index value won't matter.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this clears my confusion.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` doesn't evaluate its operand unless you pass a VLA. You can't pass it a flexible array member either because that's an incomplete type.

However, `sizeof(b[0])` is fine and well-defined, as it is an individual item of type `int`. The operand is not evaluated.